# Build webkit error on mac os x 10.9: 'WebKitSystemInterface.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, macos, webkit

When i try to build webkit-r164553 on mac os x 10.9 (xcode 5.0.2), I encounter the following build error:

> /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/Source/WebKit/mac/Plugins/Hosted/NetscapePluginHostManager.mm:33:9:
> fatal error: 'WebKitSystemInterface.h' file not found

I have set Products and Intermediates location to WebKitBuild in workspace settings.

Does anyone know why this error happened?

Here is the full log:

> CompileC
> /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NetscapePluginHostManager.o
> mac/Plugins/Hosted/NetscapePluginHostManager.mm normal x86_64
> objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>
> cd /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/Source/WebKit
>
> setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -x objective-c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-gc -Wno-trigraphs -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wsign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wnewline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDISABLE_THREAD_CHECK -DENABLE_WEBKIT_UNSET_DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH -DENABLE_3D_RENDERING -DENABLE_BLOB -DENABLE_CACHE_PARTITIONING -DENABLE_CANVAS_PATH -DENABLE_CHANNEL_MESSAGING -DENABLE_CSS_BOX_DECORATION_BREAK -DENABLE_CSS_COMPOSITING -DENABLE_CSS_EXCLUSIONS -DENABLE_CSS_FILTERS -DENABLE_CSS_REGIONS -DENABLE_CSS_SHAPES -DENABLE_CSS_SHAPE_INSIDE -DENABLE_CSS_STICKY_POSITION -DENABLE_CSS_TRANSFORMS_ANIMATIONS_UNPREFIXED -DENABLE_CURSOR_VISIBILITY -DENABLE_DASHBOARD_SUPPORT -DENABLE_DETAILS_ELEMENT -DENABLE_DOM4_EVENTS_CONSTRUCTOR -DENABLE_ENCRYPTED_MEDIA -DENABLE_ENCRYPTED_MEDIA_V2 -DENABLE_FILTERS -DENABLE_FULLSCREEN_API -DENABLE_GEOLOCATION -DENABLE_HIDDEN_PAGE_DOM_TIMER_THROTTLING -DENABLE_ICONDATABASE -DENABLE_INDEXED_DATABASE -DENABLE_INDIE_UI -DENABLE_INPUT_TYPE_COLOR -DENABLE_INPUT_TYPE_COLOR_POPOVER -DENABLE_INSPECTOR -DENABLE_LEGACY_CSS_VENDOR_PREFIXES -DENABLE_LEGACY_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_LEGACY_VENDOR_PREFIXES -DENABLE_LEGACY_WEB_AUDIO -DENABLE_MATHML -DENABLE_MEDIA_CONTROLS_SCRIPT -DENABLE_MEDIA_SOURCE -DENABLE_METER_ELEMENT -DENABLE_MOUSE_CURSOR_SCALE -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DENABLE_PAGE_VISIBILITY_API -DENABLE_PDFKIT_PLUGIN -DENABLE_PROGRESS_ELEMENT -DENABLE_PROMISES -DENABLE_PUBLIC_SUFFIX_LIST -DENABLE_REQUEST_ANIMATION_FRAME -DENABLE_REMOTE_INSPECTOR -DENABLE_SHARED_WORKERS -DENABLE_SPEECH_SYNTHESIS -DENABLE_SQL_DATABASE -DENABLE_SUBPIXEL_LAYOUT -DENABLE_SUBTLE_CRYPTO -DENABLE_SVG_FONTS -DENABLE_TEMPLATE_ELEMENT -DENABLE_USERSELECT_ALL -DENABLE_VIDEO -DENABLE_VIDEO_TRACK -DENABLE_WEBGL -DENABLE_WEB_ANIMATIONS -DENABLE_WEB_AUDIO -DENABLE_WEB_SOCKETS -DENABLE_WORKERS -DENABLE_XHR_TIMEOUT -DENABLE_XSLT -DFRAMEWORK_NAME=WebKit -DWEBKIT_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=WEBKIT_VERSION_LATEST -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
> -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/WebKit.hmap
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/include -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/usr/local/include
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/WebCore.framework/PrivateHeaders/ForwardingHeaders
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/WebCore.framework/PrivateHeaders/icu
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/DerivedSources/WebKit
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug/usr/local/include
> -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
> -I/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/DerivedSources
> -Wall -Wextra -Wchar-subscripts -Wextra-tokens -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-unused-parameter -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wexit-time-destructors -Wglobal-constructors -Wtautological-compare -Wimplicit-fallthrough -F/Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Frameworks
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Frameworks
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
> -include /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/PrecompiledHeaders/WebKitPrefix-aldduogwfpkmuvaozdblpomjxfqh/WebKitPrefix.h
> -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NetscapePluginHostManager.d
> --serialize-diagnostics /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NetscapePluginHostManager.dia
> -c /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/Source/WebKit/mac/Plugins/Hosted/NetscapePluginHostManager.mm
> -o /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/WebKitBuild/WebKit.build/Debug/WebKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NetscapePluginHostManager.o
>
> /Users/justyn/develop/project/webkit/Source/WebKit/mac/Plugins/Hosted/NetscapePluginHostManager.mm:33:9:
> fatal error: 'WebKitSystemInterface.h' file not found
>
> ## import "WebKitSystemInterface.h"
>
> ```
>     ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

Comment: Please provide a shorter and more relevant version of your output and link the rest on something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: And the error is very explicit : in the file NetscapePluginHostManager.mm line 33 character 9 there is an include for WebKitSystemInterface.h that is not resolved. You could try to remove this include as it is possible that it is not needed anymore, modify it in order to point to the correct file if you can find it or report a bug on the webkit bug tracker.

Comment: yes, I knew that file "WebKitSystemInterface.h" was not found, but it should not be happened i think. So i would like to know if i miss some configs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume you are referring to the trunk branch. The strange thing is that the bots are green for the revision you have checked out. See it at [Apple Mavericks Debug](http://build.webkit.org/builders/Apple%20Mavericks%20Debug%20%28Build%29/builds/4554) or [Apple Mavericks Release](http://build.webkit.org/builders/Apple%20Mavericks%20Release%20%28Build%29/builds/3933).

However, after a bit of debugging, I found that the file **WebKitSystemInterface.h** is located in `<webkit_root>/WebKitLibraries/WebKitSystemInterface.h`. Now, during the build phase, this file gets copied over to `<webkit_root>/WebKitBuild/<Configuration>/usr/local/include/WebKitSystemInterface.h`

I found a hack that copying over the file manually to the target folder gets you past the error. You can try it if you like till an actual fix lands in or someone having a deeper insight into the code helps you.

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks Darshak! I resolved this problem when I copied the file WebKitSystemInterface.h to <webkit_root>/WebKitBuild/<Configuration>/usr/local/include/ and I also copied libWebKitSystemInterfaceMavericks.a to <webkit_root>/WebKitBuild/<Configuration>/

Comment: But I also wonder why these file were not copied to the right dir.

Comment: Seems it is a bogus build target somewhere in the build flow, I have produced a dir `<webkit_root>/WebKitLibraries/--llvm/` and inside that a few static library from the `<webkit_root>/WebKitLibraries` and the mentioned `usr/local/include/WebKitSystemInterface.h` file. 
I've copied that `usr` folder over `<webkit_root>/WebKitBuild/<Configuration>` that worked fine too